# Height percentage of divs in IE and FireFox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I know this question has been asked a lot but I am still not getting this to work. Also I have tried vh instead of % but it doesnt scale as percentage does.

I am trying to create a box with a black background vertically aligned in the yellow div. If you change the height in `inner-left-bracket-div` then you are able to get the background perfectly aligned. But I want it to be 50% in height and not with a static value.

Is this even possible?

HTML

```
<div class="left-bracket-div">
        <div class="inner-left-bracket-div"></div>
    </div>
<div class="bracket-match">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.left-bracket-div{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner-left-bracket-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: black;
}

div.bracket-match {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    background: gray;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcSfe/2947/)

OBS: I have added 100% in height to body, html and form. Still no results.

Comment: Does the inner div have content or will it not have content at all?

Comment: Are you able to define the height of `.left-bracket-div` (parent of the target div) in pixels? If so that will work.

Comment: The inner div will contain some content generated by angular - so yes. I am not able to define the height in px of `.left-bracket-div` because my solution scales for each node generated in angular.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign a specific height to `.left-bracket-div` it will work. Try swapping out

```
 height: 100%;
```

for

```
 height: 300px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mcSfe/2977/

Comment: Thank you Nvioli. This works for IE, Safari and Chrome but not in FF?

Comment: Using the actual height of the div should work across all. I was avoiding it before for more flexibility, but if you're defining the height in `.bracket-match` maybe it's not an issue?

Answer (score -1):

I've been long searching for a solution to define a height percentage that would work the same in ie and other browsers and nothing seemed to work, ie always showed it bigger.

Having just come across this, wanted to share it. Works ferpect for me: 
http://joaocunha.github.io/vunit/

Maybe because I was anxious I didn't realize how to do it at first. In case it's helpful for someone else, here's a simple example.

You define the percentage you want it to be in the class itself (in the example class="header50" means 50%. If I just change it to class="header100" it'll be 100%). While in the script is identified as ".header" only

```
<head>
<script src="path/to/vunit.js"></script>
<script>
    new vUnit({
      CSSMap: {
        '.header': {
          property: 'height',
          reference: 'vh'
        }
      }    
    }).init();
</script>
</head>

<div id="header" class="header50">Header 50%</div>
```